# Passing recordId parameter from Aura:attribute (originally set by javascript on a VFP)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass a recordId from a visualforce page to an aura:component and finally into a LWC. The LWC is not accepting this, and because it is a managed packaged (open source), I am unable to know how or which parameters are required. It's Time Warp LWC, so it should only need recordId and objectApiName, both of which I am trying to pass:

VFP code:

```
<script>
      function jscallmethod(recordId,accountName){
        debugger;
           document.getElementById('recordpanel').innerHTML='';
                    $Lightning.use("c:XP_LightningOut", function() {
                       $Lightning.createComponent("c:XP_ProgBar",
                            {recordId : recordId,
                                objectApiName: 'Account'},
                                "recordpanel",
                                 function(cmp) {
                                console.log("component created");
                          // do some stuff
                      }
               );
               });
             }
                    </script>
```

This is the AC:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="accountName" type="String" />
 <aura:attribute name="objectApiName" type="String" />

<lightning:card title="{!v.recordId}" iconName="custom:custom30" />
<bmpyrckt:timeline recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}" />
```

</aura:component>

The lightning:card title is reading the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

@matt, Appreciate your question and happy to assist once you help me understand the below:

Why are you passing the recordId from VF page ==> Aura Component ==> LWC, any reason you can share?

Also you might be aware, but sharing below interface name in Aura that is capable of fetching the recordId from the page context.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation

In addition to Aura having interfaces which i state above, i would recommend you to use the below LWC approach to access and fetch the record context to help your implementation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_record_context

Let me know if the above helps!

Comment: Hey Sunil, thanks for your response.

The reason for passing a variable from VF -> Aura -> LWC is because the ID comes from a click event on an apex:pageblocktable, not the ID of the VFP itself. In this way, the LWC is dynamic and will show context for any record I click on the table.

I did figure out the answer, but it took the developer of the LWC to tell me the minimum required LWC set-up parameter names.